# Cannot boot into 12.04 Just flashing cursor

Tags: 12.04, boot, cursor

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP pro (almost never use the windows though). 
Been having some troubles with the machine getting very sluggish lately. Consider a poss overheating prob, then recently discovered the main system drive had some bad sectors and had a fail warning in disk utility. 
Backed up the whole Ubuntu set up so not overly worried, and actually not sure if thats the issue. Now can't boot at all, except into Windows. even trying it with the live CD keep going right back to the flashing cursor. In windows I can access all the drives (3 of em) and even see the Ubuntu partitions chi, XP management says are ok.
Puzzled.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> ...recently discovered the main system drive had some **bad sectors** and had a **fail warning** in disk utility.

This indicates an imminent hard disk failure. There is little hope that the drive will survive for any sensible period of time and needs to be replaced.

You did the right thing when making backups to make sure your data are safe. Do not forget to also backup hidden dot-files in your `/home` to safe you personal application settings including keys.

Do replace your drive as soon as possible. Make continous backups until you have done so. In case the operating systems got damaged by a harddisk defect (likely because of boot failure) you will have to install them rather than restore them from backups. Thenafter you will be able to restore your personal data from backups of your HOME.